# jQuery / JS - How can I exclude <a> with specific href in conditions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, preloader

I'm trying to exclude specific `<a>` into if statement, basing on their `href` values. More specifically I'm showing a preloader div when whatever `<a>` is clicked except for those triggering `javascript` or containing `#`. 
This makes my users see a nice screen while waiting for page load.

I've written this little js things:

```
$('a').click(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');

  //my conditions
  if ((href != '#') || (href != 'javascript:void(0);')) {
    $('#preloader').fadeIn("fast");
  }
});

//Showing preloader
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#preloader').fadeOut("slow");
});
```

My statement works excluding links containing `#` but for those with `javascript:void(0);`, it doesn't instead. This is my problem.
What am I doing wrong? Is there an error in statement or in values?

Comment: Could you provide some markup with your example? At a first glance, your handler _should_ work correctly. Perhaps you have a typo in your anchor's href

Comment: @Seth Thank you for your reply, I've already fixed it implementing the answer below. Have a great day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two immediate approaches I can think of to address your problem with the given code:

1. Your conditions are incorrect. `if((href != '#') || (href != 'javascript:void(0);'))` should be `if(href != '#' && href != 'javascript:void(0);')`
2. Optimally, exclude irrelevant elements from the query itself:

```js
$('a').not('[href="#"]').not('[href="javascript:void(0);"]).click(function() {
    $('#preloader').fadeIn("fast");
});
```

See jQuery's [Attribute Not Equal Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/).

Comment: I disagree with your first statement. It shouldn't be a logical AND since a href is contains either `#` OR `javascript:void(0);`. If it contains both then someone is doing something incorrectly. Also the OP requests it to be for either OR. However your suggestion of using `.not` is definitely what the OP is looking for

Comment: Bomb! I've tried and evolved the second method. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @Seth, the conditions are negated, so `&&` is what you'd want: anchors whose `href` attributes are **not** `#` **and not** `javascript:void(0);`: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yuyoa060/)

Answer (score 0):

This answer May help someone .. and another way to check

```
if($(this).is(':not([href^="#"]):not([href^="javascript:"])')){
   $('#preloader').fadeIn("fast");
}
```

```js
$('a').on('click',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 if($(this).is(':not([href^="#"]):not([href^="javascript:"])')){
   alert('Good');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
  click
</a><br />
<a href="#">
  click
</a><br />

<a href="go">
  click
</a><br />
```